# How to make the bottom of a div curved with a straight line?

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm having problems trying to make the bottom of my div to look like [this](https://ibb.co/6bG4VN5).
I tried using border radius to get the curved result at the bottom right but I don't know how can I create this straight line at an angle.
Here's my current [code](https://codepen.io/Arconi/pen/MWELjjr).

```
<div>The code is in the link</div>
```

Comment: You need to design a **diagonal div** and add `border radius` to the right corner  https://codepen.io/christophergoodwin/pen/mVEGyE

Answer (score 1):

##### Check out this code and use the transform property *Perspective*

`transform: perspective(value);`

The mention thing is an illustration used as the background image. It would be a good practice if you try it so check out my Codepen Work for source code.

```css
.innerlayer{
  width: 650px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #00bcd4;
  margin: auto;
  transform: perspective(1000px) rotatey(18deg);
  border-bottom-right-radius: 35%;
  
}

.outerlayer{
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px;
}

.tophidden{
  width: auto;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: -80px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  
}
```

```html
<div class="outerlayer">
  <div class="tophidden">
<div class="innerlayer"></div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

> Watch it in full screen view

Comment: This makes the content appear at an angle too.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use **:before** pseudo element, and skew it.

[Here you can find your modified code](https://codepen.io/yaroslav-trach/pen/wvPBXbO)

```scss
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
    // make sure wrapper of pseudo has position: relative
    position: relative;
  
    &:before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: -1;
        background: linear-gradient(72deg, rgba(100,36,220,1) 0%, rgba(118,107,254,1) 100%);
  
        // set border radius size
        border-bottom-right-radius: 10rem;
        // set skew angle
        transform: skewY(-2deg);
        transform-origin: left bottom;
    }
    

    .container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        max-width: 1270px;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 1.125rem 1.5rem 1.125rem 1.5rem;
    }

    .logo {
        color: white;
        margin-right: 3em;
        text-transform: lowercase;
        font-size: 42px;
        align-items: center;
        font-weight:700;
    }

    nav {
        display: flex;
        margin-top: 1em;
    }

    .primary-nav {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .nava {
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: 400;
    }

    a {
        color: white;
        margin-right: 1em;
    }

    .second-nav {
        display: flex; 
        align-items: center;
    }

    .contact-nav {
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: 700;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: #5008d9;
        background:white;
        border-radius: 360px;
        padding: 0.9rem 2rem 0.9rem 2rem;
    }

    .cda {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        padding-top: 5em;
        padding-bottom: 5em;
    }

    .cta-left {
        height: 100%;
        width: 50%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin-top: 5em;
        padding-bottom: 15em;
    }

    h2 {
        color: white;
        font-size: 70px;
        font-weight: 600;
        line-height: 1.0;
    }

    p {
        color: white;
    }

    .cta-right {
        width: 50%;
    }

    img {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .cta-p {
        margin-top: 2em;
    }

    .learn-more {
        margin-top: 3em;
    }

    .learn {
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: 500;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: black;
        background:#00dadc;
        border-radius: 360px;
        padding: 0.9rem 4rem 0.9rem 4rem;
    }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="container">
      <nav>
        <ul class="primary-nav">
          <a class="logo" href="#">Agency</a>
          <li><a class="nava" href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a class="nava" href="#">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a class="nava" href="#">Our Services</a></li>
          <li><a class="nava" href="#">Support</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <nav>
        <ul class="second-nav">
          <li><a class="contact-nav" href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="cda">
        <div class="cta-left">
          <h2>Creative <br> Design Agency</h2>
          <p class="cta-p">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. <br> Etiam vel dolor id nulla gravida blandit.</p>
          <div class="learn-more">
            <a class="learn" href="#">Learn More</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cta-right">
          <img src="images/doge.jpeg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```